# Drupal url Alias weird behavior

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, url-routing, pathauto

I have created content type and set that to default url alias for all content. But that is not working that start working after clearing the cache, But after some non specific time it stop working. Can any one please let me know the reason behind this weird behavior of url alias. There are other content types also and it works properly for them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. We have used memcache as caching  mechanism and it went down and when we restated it back it have loaded the cached data from drupal database. so there were old path token in the cache which caused issue.